# Arc Length Clarification Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was given the following prompt:

> What is the length of the curve $y=1-\cos(x)$ from $x=0$ to $x=4\pi$?

I was able to set up an integral and find a numerical answer for this problem, but I just wanted some clarification as to whether or not this is correct. I set up the integral of: $$L=\int_0^{4\pi}\sqrt{1+[\sin(x)]^2}\,dx$$ and I found the answer of $15.281$ from this integral, any clarification about whether or not this is correct would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks correct..

Comment: Two comments about Mathjax: Use `\sin(x)` instead of `sin(x)` so that you display $\sin(x)$ rather than $sin(x)$, and second, use `\sqrt{}` rather than `\sqrt()` to display $\sqrt{1 + [\sin(x)]^2}$ rather than $\sqrt(1+[\sin(x)]^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have applied the [arc length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating) correctly:
$$
\int_a^b\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\,dx
$$

You then got an [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) and you have the correct approximate value.